# Install poppler onto Heroku Server django

Tags: django, heroku, poppler

I am trying to install `poppler` on my Heroku server because I am using `pdf2image` as a python package. However, I can't just run `brew install poppler` like I did on my Mac.

I have tried to add some heroku buildpacks off the internet but with no luck. Anytime pdf2image runs I get this error.

```
pdf2image.exceptions.PDFInfoNotInstalledError: Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH?
```

Is there something I can do on the command line to get poppler installed while keeping heroku/python as my buildpack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there something I can do on the command line to get poppler installed while keeping `heroku/python` as my buildpack?

[Heroku lets you run multiple buildpacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app). I haven't tried this buildpack, but I'd recommend adding [this buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/survantjames/heroku-buildpack-poppler) to your existing app:

```
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/python
heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 https://github.com/survantjames/heroku-buildpack-poppler.git
```

Then redeploy your application.

Answer (score 5):

You can install APT packages with an [experimental function](https://help.heroku.com/IYRYW6VB/how-do-i-install-additional-software-packages-that-my-application-requires) on Heroku

Steps:

1. Add the buildpack to Heroku.

   ```
   heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku-community/apt
   ```
2. Make a file named `Aptfile` in your project folder and write `poppler-utils` inside.
3. Commit and push.